# Browser or IDE ( Eclipse ) don't complain about missing JS function

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

I have this piece of code in my jsp,

`<spring-form:radiobutton path="selectedIndex"   value="${counter}"  onclick="radioCheck('${counter}');" />`

JS Function `radioCheck` has still not been coded.

When I run jsp in `IE11` , no complaints or warnings after clicking radio button and I don't see any warnings in Eclipse either.

Am I missing something or is that the normal behavior?

Comment: Did you click on radio button and then check console?

Comment: There I see error about undefined function. no warnings to end user?